# Criar uma div que ocupe uma largura de 100% da tela?

Tags: css, div

Criei uma `<div>` mas ela não esta ocupando 100% da parte superior que eu quero veja: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAgKv.png
ela esta com um espaçamento por volta :(

este é o código que usei:

```
css:
.top-bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #313D4C;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente adicionar um `margin: 0` a essa `div`, e um `margin: 0; padding: 0;` ao `body`. Ficaria assim:

```
 body{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
 .top-bar {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 60px;
     background: #313D4C;
     margin: 0;
 }
```

Contudo, o ideal seria uma aplicação desses estilos a todos os elementos, você conseguiria isso por meio do seletor `*` do css, fica assim:

```
*{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
```

Além disso você poderia colocar um `border-box: box-sizing`, muito bem explicado [**nesse artigo**](http://sergiolopes.org/css-box-sizing-border-box/). Ele faria com que as determinções de tamanhos dos elementos, já levassem em consideração por si só margens, espaçamentos, bordas, entre outras coisas.

Comment: Obrigado cara, resolveu aqui.

Mas se eu usar o * nao vai acabar bugando outros elementos ?

Comment: Isso vai depender do seu código, teste e veja. Normalmente não, já que ele irá levar em consideração os styles paticulares a cada elemento. Então se você determinou margens, estas continuaram lá.

Answer (score 0):

Ta usando algum reset?
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

Pode ser a falta de algum reset, pois os browsers tem um margin default de 8px.

Ou tenta por como block:

.topbar { display: block; width: 100%; height: 60px; }